# MySQLi procedural query, what's wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
//Successful connection to $db

function insert_users($db, $username, $password, $email)
{
    echo "FUNCTION CALLED"; //This is outputted successfully

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($db);

    if(mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $query))
    {
        echo "QUERY PREPARED"; // rest of code was snipped (will put up upon request)
    } else {
        echo "QUERY DENIED"; //This is outputted successfully
    }
}


//The $user $pass and $mail are defined and then the function is called

insert_users($db, $user, $pass, $mail);
```

Database structure:

```
testdb (database)
    -> users (table)
        -> id            //Primary key, unique key
        -> username      //unique key
        -> password
        -> email
```

Why doens't the query go through with it's operation?
It echoes "Query denied" instead of "Query prepared". The query is invalid I believe. If more information is required, ill be happy to edit this question

**EDIT**

I added

`mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);`after the `echo "QUERY DENIED";`
nothing happens...

**EDIT 2**

```
$server = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$password = '';
$databse = 'testdb';

$db = @mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $database) or die("Could not connect to Database server. Please inform an administrator");
```

That's my database setup. Do i put the variables in quotes?

Comment: Please show [`mysqli_stmt_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php), when your prepare fails.

Comment: You are trying to insert empty string into primary key column. Is it legal in your scenario? is PK autoincrement?

Comment: @Olaf Dietsche okay, will do :)

Comment: @Hamlet Hakobyan as Olaf answered, it is auto_increment

Comment: More information is required. What is the error message? Mysqli provides you error information, you only need (and you really should) get if from `$db` and / or `$stmt`. If you have trouble to locate that, let me know, I can pass you the links (hint: it's all in the manual).

Comment: Just echo the string from `mysqli_stmt_error()`. It will tell you what's wrong.

Comment: wooooow. "No database selected." (look at edit 2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id` is an auto_increment column, you can just drop it from your insert

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

You have a typo in `$databse = 'testdb';`. Rename it to `$database`.

Comment: I'm ashamed at my ridiculous mistake :( Thank you very much (everyone).

Comment: from you original query, instead of inserting `''`, replace it with `NULL`, eg `INSERT INTO users (id, username, password, email) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?)`

Answer (score 2):

I imagine it is because you are always trying to enter an empty string as your primary key (`id`).  If that field is an auto-incrementing field, you should not even both trying to set a value for it.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```

Comment: I still get a "QUERY DENIED"...